# how do I make Python tkinter message box show a number from elsewhere in the script

Tags: python, tkinter

Will preface this by saying i am very new to python and coding in general,
I followed a tutorial on how to make a countdown timer, and have managed to code a button that measures the amount of times it has been clicked by mashing my code for the button with a post i found on a forum, the count down timer displays a "Times up" message box at the end, what i want to do is have it also display the amount of times the button is clicked in the allotted time. I've tried calling the global count from within the countdown timer and reusing the line that displays the count in the GUI but this seems to break it and doing it without it as displayed here simply shows the string as it is written, any help or guidance is appreciated

'''

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

f = ("Arial",24)

root = Tk()
root.title("Click Counter") 
root.config(bg='#345')
root.state('zoomed') #opens as maximised, negating the need for the 'Geometry' command

count = 0

def clicked(): 
    global count

    count = count + 1

    myLabel.configure(text=f'Button was clicked {count} times!!!')

hour=StringVar()
minute=StringVar()
second=StringVar()

hour.set("00")
minute.set("00")
second.set("10")

hour_tf= Entry(
    root, 
    width=3, 
    font=f,
    textvariable=hour
    )

hour_tf.place(x=80,y=20)

mins_tf= Entry(
    root, 
    width=3, 
    font=f,
    textvariable=minute)

mins_tf.place(x=130,y=20)

sec_tf = Entry(
    root, 
    width=3, 
    font=f,
    textvariable=second)

sec_tf .place(x=180,y=20)

    
TheButton = Button(root, height= 30, width=100, bg="light blue", text="Click For Your Life", command=clicked) #tells the button to call the function when clicked

TheButton.pack()

myLabel = Label(root) 
myLabel.pack()  


def startCountdown():
    
    try:
        userinput = int(hour.get())*3600 + int(minute.get())*60 + int(second.get())
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning('', 'Invalid Input!')
    while userinput >-1:
        mins,secs = divmod(userinput,60) 

        hours=0
        if mins >60:
            
        
            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
    
        hour.set("{0:2d}".format(hours))
        minute.set("{0:2d}".format(mins))
        second.set("{0:2d}".format(secs))

    
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

    
        if (userinput == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("Time's Up!!", "you clicked (count) times")
        

        userinput -= 1




start_btn = Button(
    root, 
    text='START', 
    bd='5',
    command= startCountdown
    )

start_btn.place(x = 120,y = 120)



root.mainloop()
'''
```

Comment: I wonder why you can't do the same thing in `showinfo()` as how you show the number of counts in a label inside `clicked()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an f-String with "{}", like you did in the `clicked` function:

```
if (userinput == 0):
    messagebox.showinfo(f"Time's Up!! you clicked {count} times")
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion as well just to see if it worked and the code remained broken, thank you for your help though

Comment: I think it should be `messagebox.showinfo("Time's Up!!", f"you clicked {count} times")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A kind user provided the correct answer but has seen fit to delete their comment so in case anyone like me is trawling through old posts looking for help here is what worked:

> To have your messagebox display the number of clicks (in this case
> count), you can simply use
>
> ```
> messagebox.showinfo("Time's Up!!", "you clicked " + str(count) +  " times")
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> messagebox.showinfo("Time's Up!!", "you clicked (count) times")
> ```
>
> Your attempt won't work, because you included count inside the
> quotation marks, meaning that Python will completely ignore the fact
> that count is also a variable and just print it as a string. There are
> a lot of ways you can format strings to include variables etc. Check
> out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for a good tutorial/explanation.